# FireFox URL To Desktop Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am using an Apple Mac Mini OS is 10.13.6.  My default browser is Firefox 65.0.1.  I also have the Opera browser installed in the Applications folder.

When ever I drag a URL to the Desktop the Icon shows as a white Icon with a red "O". When I right click on the Icon and go to Get Information the URL has .WEBLOC and the Change is greyed out.  I am aware that the .WEBLOC is the result of Safari being installed and integrated into the OS by Apple, but why am I not getting a Firefox Icon (which is the default)
on the Desktop instead of the Opera Icon?

I have checked & confirmed that Firefox is set as the default browser in both the OS System Preferences as well as in FF Preferences.

Comment: I think you should ask this question in https://apple.stackexchange.com/ as this question is more about why OSX works or doesn't work in a certain way. Also, Firefox is a web browser, not a web app.  If you need a quick and dirty workaround you could always use Applescript until you have a solution. https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=21304.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was looking for an appreciate place - did not find Apply Exchange listed anywhere,